# Get a Windows Form to behave similar to a taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

I've got a problem (well, rather no clue how to do something) about my Windows Form.
I have set up a windows form that, much like the task bar, goes from the left to the right of the screen. Now I would like it to, instead of being "above" other windows, "push" them down / make them smaller so they fit between a sort of "top-task-bar" and the normal taskbar - here you have a screenshot of what it looks like right now:

[image: (Please ignore the red bars)]

As you can see, it's in the way of other programs' controls etc.. Since I would like it to stay TopMost, I have to do what the task bar does - decrease the working area so programs have no problems but it's still there. I'm using Windows Forms.

Any advice on how to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: It can only *act* like a taskbar when you tell Explorer that it is *is* a taskbar.  That requires pinvoking SHAppBarMessage().  Find code samples by googling "windows forms shappbarmessage".  Lots of hits, first one is good.

Comment: [What if two programs did this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413) comes to mind

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! Going to google that now.

Comment: See [Using Application Desktop Toolbars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776821.aspx)

Comment: @stu MSDN: _Any number of appbars can exist on the desktop at any given time._

Comment: @stuart There is actually a supported API for this, so it's not one of the typical cases. Two programs can do this without a problem. You can actually have multiple app bars anchored to a single edge of the screen. Now, I'm not saying it's a good idea. You'll notice there aren't many apps using this API anymore. Microsoft Office was one of the few that did, back in the day, and it didn't last very long.